# Interactive proof of possession of a signed message

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, interactive-proofs, u-prove

Suppose Alice has a verifiable (message, signature) pair from Cedric, who would not cooperate and routinely uses an algo (ecdsa, eddsa, rsa, or *insert yours here*) to sign messages.

Alice wants to **interactively** prove to Bob she has that (message, signature) pair with the valid signature, obviously. It doesn't have to be "zero-knowledge" - she might divulge bits and pieces, but it shouldn't be less hard for Bob to recover complete (message, signature) pair than for Alice to forge the signature altogether.

Obviously, Alice and Bob both have Cedric's public key. I look for an interactive procedure and stochastic proof. Preferably with existing implementations.

Comment: what if you split the message in 100 parts with different signature and give little part of the parts

Comment: and then maybe add a second signed message containing only 10 part equally disdributed with the relative signature + the signature of the whole message

Comment: @zjmo and then maybe 10 people named Bob talk to each other :-)

Comment: just started reding crypto for dummies ;)